# Git remote head points to a branch, not master

Tags: git, version-control, github

The `origin/HEAD` points to my feature branch and not `master`.

This happened after I rolled back some commits in my local repository and pushed this change to the `origin`.

I created the pull request to merge `policy` into `master`, but it does not work, just sits there.

The graph looks like this:
[image]

Comment: How do you know that `origin/HEAD` is pointing to your feature branch? This is not clear from the screenshot.

Comment: Based on your pull request comment, I wonder if you're really just trying to merge `origin/policy` into `origin/master`. Assuming you have write access to the repository, `merge` your local copies of these branches and then `push` to `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

Github's `HEAD` points to whichever branch is set to be your default. You can [select your default branch in your repository settings](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch).

Comment: Thank you. The "main branch" was set to be "master" all the time. I tried this back and forth, but it did not work... 
Any suggestions?